# Can anyone tell me the name of this manga?

Tags: shin-am-heng-eo-sa

[image]
Think it's a manhwa but don't know which one so I was wondering if anyone could please tell me where it's from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is this picture from? How do I use Reverse Image Search to find the source of an anime/manga image?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/21618/where-is-this-picture-from-how-do-i-use-reverse-image-search-to-find-the-source)

Answer (score 5):

The manga is

Shin Am Heng Eo Sa (Shin Angyō Onshi) Manhwa

[Check here](http://www.mangawolf.com/shin-am-heng-eo-sa)

Comment: umm accpeting this answer would be appreciated.